# Answer from combobox

Tags: combobox, radio-group

I have 9 comboboxes with 3 radio groupbuttons.
Made a separate button to display a total

example:
if cmbItems.itemindex = 0 then

```
begin
   if rbgcompany.itemindex = 0 then
   begin
   const
   ijean = 125.50;

    rans1 := ijean * iq;
    Mem1.Lines.Add(inttostr(iq) + #9 + 'jean' + #9 + floattostrf(rans1,
    ffcurrency, 8, 2));
  end
else

   if rbgcompany.itemindex = 1 then
    begin
    const
    ijean = 127.99;

    rans1 := ijean * iq;
    Mem1.Lines.Add(inttostr(iq) + #9 + 'jean' + #9 + floattostrf(rans1,
    ffcurrency, 8, 2))

  end
else

   if rbgcompany.itemindex = 2 then
  begin
   const
  ijean = 128.50;

   rans1:= ijean * iq;
   Mem1.Lines.Add(inttostr(iq) + #9 + 'jean' + #9 + floattostrf(rans1,
  ffcurrency, 8, 2));
   end;
  end;
```

end;
if
if cmbItems.itemindex = 1 then
begin
..................///repeat code for new item from index

I cannot get the rans1, rans2,rans3...... from combobox to
add up to the total button for display.
please help

to add up the rTotal for Total button